# Fullscreen webview xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, webview, fullscreen

I'm developing a new app in xamarin forms (crossed app) using xaml/C#. In a page called webview.xaml I have insert the webview

```
var browser = new WebView {
    Source = "http://xamarin.com"
};
```

When I play a video with webview I can't view it in fullscreen mode. 
How can I enable the fullscreen mode?

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 1):

In the Xamarin Android project add this:

```
//Remove title bar
RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
//Remove notification bar
Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
```

It should work.